# In monitor mode but not sniffing packets :(

Tags: raspbian, wifi

Ok so now I have finally got over the problem of putting in in monitor mode, my program (a google search sniffer that shows unencrypted google searches) won't actually display any google searches. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you think the Raspberry Pi has anything to do with your problem?

Comment: I doubt it, I asked on the Pi forum if monitor mode was supported by the WiPi and they said they used it for a wifi jammer. To be honest I don't know. Monitor mode seems to take up a lot of the CPU...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have enough rep yet to answer or ask questions in the discussion section, but by any chance is your application passing packets through it or copying them onto temporary storage for later access?

If it is just passing packets then that could explain why you arn't able to sniff packets, maybe as a temp check if you can send sniffed data onto local storage then present it on the screen.

Also if your topology consists of your pi connected wirelessly to a router and the computer is connected to the same router check for any settings on the router on the lines of ap isolation, I've heard that there can be problems with packet sniffing if the raspberry pi isn't an intermediate device between the client and the internet.

Hope this helps mate and good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to go with an answer here, since I cannnot comment yet: 
Google does not support un-encrypted queries anymore - only https/ssl.
Could that be your part of your problem?

And if you are in monitor mode, how would you expect to sniff google-specific packages?

Comment: That will be why then.

Comment: I can sniff them from my own device but not others. Also they are http requests with Google specific things in.